# google font Roboto, difference between Firefox and Chrome, ONLY MY PC

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, roboto

Using a Windows operating system, ONLY ON MY PC
you see the difference? (see photo)
Google Chrome is the same character on Roboto Roboto Condensed. Why? I do not understand. ONLY PROBLEM ON MY PC FIXED ONLY ON CHROME
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWO2Q.jpg]

Comment: Use a Reset CSS and say if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Another person: https://twitter.com/GaryCottington/status/555747977969823745  had this issue, we're seeing this in Chrome as well. Could very well be the woff2 file was uploaded incorrectly by Google.